# CDI Injection in EJB from WAR doesn't retain original object

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jax-rs, cdi

The question in general is: does CDI injection works when a CDI bean is created via a producer field in a JAX-RS service (WAR file) while its consumption is made within EJB bean (EJB file)?

Based on this question [Is it possible to @Inject a @RequestScoped bean into a @Stateless EJB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717022/is-it-possible-to-inject-a-requestscoped-bean-into-a-stateless-ejb) such scenario should work but I can't get this working.

Here are some details. I've a very simple JavaEE application (https://github.com/kocherovms/develorium.com/tree/master/cdi_problem) with following structure:

```
hello-ear:
 |
 +- hello-ejb
 |   |
 |   +- HelloBean
 |
 +- hello-war
     |
     +- HelloService
```

In this application I'm trying to pass via CDI injection a `Guest` object between JAX-RS service (hello-war) and EJB bean (hello-ejb). Here is the JAX-RS service which produces an instance of a `Guest` object:

```
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloService {
    @EJB
    private Hello hello;

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    @GuestMarker
    private Guest guest;

    @GET
    public Response perform() {
        guest = new Guest();
        guest.setName("white rabbit");
        String text = hello.getHelloText();
        return Response.ok().type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).entity(text).build();
    }
}
```

Implementation of `Hello` from hello-ejb  tries to consume a `Guest` object via CDI `@Inject`:

```
@Stateless
public class HelloBean implements Hello {
    @Inject
    @GuestMarker
    Guest guest;

    @Override
    public String getHelloText() {
        return String.format("Hello, %s!\n", guest.getName());
    }
}
```

I'm deploying this application into WildFly 10 server. Deployment itself works fine and my service is working. However invocation of a service ( `curl http://localhost:8080/hello`) always returns *'Hello, null!'* instead of *'Hello, white rabbit!'*.

This means that a `Guest` object produced on `HelloService` side is not available within `HelloBean` and a default constructed `Guest` instance is used.
I've tried various scopes (e.g. `SessionScoped`, `ApplicationScoped`), tried to use a producer method, tried making bean to be stateful and even singleton. Nothing works. It seems CDI is always using a `Dependant` scope for my case.

Is it possible to pass an instance of a `Guest` object from `HelloService` to `HelloBean`?

Comment: There is no need for those two `guest`s are same instance. Change the `@Produces` annotation with `@Inject` then the container *MAY* inject the same instance for the EJB and the JAX-RS resource.

Comment: Hi, Jin. Changing `@Produces` -> `@Inject` is not something I need. What I need is that the same bean under `@Produces` in JAX-RS (HelloService) is available at injection point in EJB (HelloBean). By doing this I want to convey some context information from JAX-RS to EJB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be over complicating your setup.  Producer fields are evaluated once, so the fact that you're mutating it is an issue.  Your producer should look like

```
@Produces
@RequestScoped
@GuestMarker
private Guest guest = new Guest();
```

And then just call the setter in the JAX-RS method, instead of instantiating it.  But that won't solve your problem, now that I realize you're using an EAR.  The scope of CDI beans is within the module associated.  So the EJB is its own context not shared with your JAX-RS resource.

Comment: John, seems you are right regarding context sharing. After I've moved HelloBean into the war file (next to HelloService) the issue is gone. 
Anyway can you point me where I could read about CDI beans visibility related to my issue?
Thanks!